# AngularJS : sharing controller between states in angular-ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have these router.js inside my ionic app ,

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

     .state('app.myprofile', {
    url: "/myprofile",
       abstract: true,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
          controller : "myprofileCtrl",
        templateUrl: "templates/myprofile.html"
      }
    }
  })
       .state('app.myprofile.info', {
    url: "/info",
 controller: "profileinfoCtrl",

        templateUrl: "templates/profile/info.html"

  })
        .state('app.myprofile.location', {

    url: "/location",
 controller: "profilelocationCtrl",

        templateUrl: "templates/profile/location.html"

  })


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

I need a way to share controller scopes between myprofile state and myprofile.location state and myprofile.info state too .

I am using ionic framework

in myprofileCtrl

```
       myapp.controller("myprofileCtrl",function($scope,Authy ,Auth,$http ,$rootScope){
                  $scope.view_loading = true;
                   Authy.can_go().then(function(data){
$scope.profile =data.profile;

});
});
```

in profilelocationCtrl

```
 myapp.controller("profilelocationCtrl",function($scope,Authy ,Auth,$http ,$rootScope){
     console.log($scope.profile);

});
```

I got undefined in the console

Comment: You already are, since location is a child of myprofile, it will use it's parent controller.

Comment: I will make an update to show you my problem

Comment: @RemonAmin Did you try mu suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that since `$scope.profile` is set after an ajax call, when the `myprofile.location` state is reached initially, then profile variable is still undefined on the parent `$scope`, what you could do is `$watch` the profile variable, or better just broadcast an event downwards when you receive it fro the server call using `$broadcast`.

`$broadcast` dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes, so you could do:

```
myapp.controller("myprofileCtrl",function($scope,Authy ,Auth,$http ,$rootScope){
     $scope.view_loading = true;
     Authy.can_go().then(function(data){
        $scope.profile =data.profile;
        $scope.$broadcast('profileSet', data.profile);
     });
});
```

and in the myprofile.location` state:

```
myapp.controller("profilelocationCtrl",function($scope,Authy,Auth,$http,$rootScope){
      $scope.$on('profileSet', function(event, data) { 
          console.log(data);
        });
      }

});
```

Have a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/VI2GQB9JowfobkfnZ3Nh?p=preview) demo plunk I just made.

Comment: it works when I reload the view ,but when I click a tab and navigate to the location tabs ,the app breaks !!!

Comment: You should make a plunk